# python requests authorization fails when json.dumps included

Tags: python, json, box-api

EDIT:

How can I replicate the following `curl` request in python?

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/files/content
-H "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN" -d '{"name": "Wolves owners.ppt", "parent": {"id": "2841136315"}, "size": 15243}' 
-X OPTIONS`
```

---

When I introduce json.dumps to the request authorization fails

the following request body wasn't formatted correctly. It was just a python dictionary and the nested attributes didn't go through.

```
h.kwargs['body'] = {"size": 45810, "parent": {"id": "2841136315"}, "name": "83db7037-2037-4f38-8349-255299343e6d"}

first = requests.options(
        h.kwargs['url'], headers=h.headers, data=h.kwargs['body']
    )
```

looking at the response the body was set to `size=45810&parent=id&name=83db7037-2037-4f38-8349-255299343e6d`

the headers were

```
`{'Content-Length': '62', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Authorization': 'Bearer TOKEN', 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'python...'}`
```

on the second request the authorization fails with a `401` once json.dumps is introduced

```
second = requests.options(
        h.kwargs['url'], headers=h.headers, data=json.dumps(h.kwargs['body'])
    )
```

the headers were

```
`{'Content-Length': '95', 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'python...', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Authorization': 'Bearer TOKEN'}`
```

How can I format the body to get the call through without messing up authorization?

I've tried setting the content type for the second request to json but it did not work

Comment: what http response did you get for the first request where fields were sent as `x-www-form-urlencoded` ?

Comment: @Anentropic `Invalid value \'size=75&parent=id&name=6951cd4f-f037-44da-9710-821dd9089486.csv`

Comment: what API are you sending the request to?

Comment: @Anentropic `400` Box [PreFlightCheck](https://developers.box.com/docs/#files-preflight-check)

Comment: so, the first request was just wrong, request should be json formatted. it looks like maybe your token is invalid?  you did put a real token in there and not just `TOKEN` ?

Comment: @Anentropic Hm I assumed I was able to authorize but the request wasn't formatted and received a `400`. The token is correct because I was able to send the request using CURL and the same token.

Comment: so the question is what is different about your curl request to the python one - I'm assuming you received a `400` to the first request but it was _also_ not authorized

Comment: @Anentropic yes. I probably should have phrased it that way. `curl https://api.box.com/2.0/files/content -H "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN" -d '{"name": "Wolves owners.ppt", "parent": {"id": "2841136315"}, "size": 15243}' -X OPTIONS `

Comment: try just `headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer TOKEN'}` ...you don't need to manually specify all the other request headers, requests will fill some in for you

Comment: @Anentropic that is the only header I am specifying `h.headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer TOKEN'}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit 2**

I have found that the `id` field is required. Your request doesn't have a value for `id` (the id of the parent folder) and that is why you are receiving HTTP status 400. The API seems a bit weird here; why does the parent folder id need to specified twice?

Anyway, the minimum required fields are `parent` and `id`. `name` and `size` are not required but their values will be checked if supplied, i.e. name validated and size compared to quota and available storage.

I also found that curl and Python generate the same 400 response when the `id` field is omitted. Perhaps you had included `id` in your curl tests?

Finally, the `Content-type` header has no affect.

Here is the revised Python code.

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://api.box.com/2.0/files/content'
h.headers = {'Authorization':'Bearer TOKEN'}
parent_folder_id = "2843500681"    # replace with your folder id

h.kwargs = {"name": "Wolves owners.ppt",
            "parent": {"id": parent_folder_id},
            "id": parent_folder_id,
            "size": 15243}

resp = requests.options(url, headers=h.headers, data=json.dumps(h.kwargs))
```

**Edit 1: after question updated**

To send the same request as does curl:

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.box.com/2.0/files/content'
h.headers = {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
             'Authorization':'Bearer TOKEN'}    

h.kwargs = {"name": "Wolves owners.ppt",
            "parent": {"id": "2841136315"},
            "size": 15243}

resp = requests.options(url, headers=h.headers, data=json.dumps(h.kwargs))
```

Note that this explicitly sets the Content-type header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as does curl. Otherwise there is no significant difference in the request.

Also note that the body in this request is not actually `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, it is just a string. Setting Content-type to `application/json` would seem more appropriate.

Here is the curl request:

```
OPTIONS /2.0/files/content HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.32.0
Host: api.box.com
Accept: */*
Authorization: Bearer TOKEN
Content-Length: 76
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

{"name": "Wolves owners.ppt", "parent": {"id": "2841136315"}, "size": 15243}
```

And here is the request generated by the code above:

```
OPTIONS /2.0/files/content HTTP/1.1
Host: api.box.com
Content-Length: 76
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
User-Agent: python-requests/2.5.0 CPython/2.7.5 Linux/3.17.4-200.fc20.x86_64
Connection: keep-alive
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: Bearer TOKEN

{"name": "Wolves owners.ppt", "parent": {"id": "2841136315"}, "size": 15243}
```

Comment: as mentioned above, I tried this and it did not work

Comment: You didn't say what you set it to. Did you try `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `application/json` or both? Anyway, answer updated.

Comment: are you sure curl is sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? Box API docs don't say anything about needing to send a content type header

Comment: @Anentropic - yes curl sets that header. I have added the actual requests to the answer.

Comment: @user2954587 - see updated answer, the problem is a missing `id` field in the request.

Comment: @mhawke I'm still unable to authorize. My request is identical to yours and it returns a `401`. the request headers are `{'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.3.0 CPython/3.4.0 Linux/3.13.0-33-generic', 'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Content-Length': '117', 'Authorization': 'Bearer TOKEN', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate'}`. I'm confident the acccess token is correct because I can past it into a `curl` request and receive a response.

Comment: Is this when you run the code in edit 2? That code works for me, so I suspect that it must be the token. From what I read, box tokens expire after 1 hour. You need to refresh them using the refresh token that was returned when you obtained the original token. Maybe you can try to generate a new token and try again.